# Como alterar o nome no pacote da aplicação android?

Tags: java, android

O nome atual do meu pacote é `com.newapp.nomedopacote`. Pois bem, caso eu queira alterá-lo para `com.newapp.novopacote`, sem que haja danos na aplicação. Tentei fazer simplesmente um refactor e ele perdeu o arquivo R.

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 3):

Bem, de antemão, só queria lhe dizer que a classe `R` sempre é criada depois do Build. Então se você mudou a package do seu projeto, lembre-se de dar um `clean project` e depois um `build project`. Certo, agora vamos mudar a package do seu projeto.

> Alterar package em app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.mypack.myoldpack"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "R15.0c"
}
```

> Alterar linha applicationId para sua nova package

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.mypack.mynewpack"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "R15.0c"
}
```

> Alterar package no AndroidManifest.xml

```
package="co.mypack.myoldpack"
```

Após ter alterado a linha acima para `package="co.mypack.mynewpack"`, você vai ter que criar um novo pacote em `main/java/.` e depois, passar todas as suas classes (copiar e colar) para o novo pacote e, enfim, apagar seu pacote antigo.